# ReactJS - Props & Components out of sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on a web-app using ReactJS & Redux on the frontend, and I'm seeing a component behave "out of sync" - where the child component (receiving props from a parent component) is rendering before receiving props. As a result, the child component throws an error during the first render, prior to the component receiving the data, as props at this time is undefined.

In other words:

Component A receives the user's data via redux and state, and passes it Component B to be displayed. When Component B renders first, it does not read the props that Component A passes, adn throws an error. However, if we don't try to render the props data and just log our data to the console, I see component B rerendering 3 times, where the first time props is undefined, and the second and third times props is received and all data is present.

**How can I make sure that all props are received before rendering, to ensure that the component B is receiving the props before rendering?**

**Component A**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import B from './B';

const A = ({ user }) => {
   return (
      <B user={user} />
   )
}

A.propTypes = {
   user: PropTypes.object
}
const mapStateToProps = state = ({ user: state.user });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(A);
```

**Component B**:

```
import React from 'react';

const B = props => {
   const user = props.user;
   const username = user.username;
   return (
      <div>
         {username}  // throws an error on render, as props.user is undefined
      </div>
   )
}

export default B;
```

I've tried to use useEffect to load props, but this error still occurs even with useEffect. The reason why I'm not nesting Component B inside Component A is because I also have Component C (public component) that is using Component B as a container for data.

Any ideas on how to tackle this "out-of-sync" rendering?

---

Solution Found!
There was a small issue with the way I was updating my redux state, and added a loading barrier to Component A in order to ensure that all was completely loaded before rendering Component A (with Component B nested within).

**Component A**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import B from './B';

const A = ({ user, loaded }) => {
   if (!loaded) {
      return "Loading"
   }
   return (
      <B user={user} />
   )
}

A.propTypes = {
   user: PropTypes.object,
   loaded: PropTypes.bool
}
const mapStateToProps = state = ({ user: state.user, loaded: state.user.loaded });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(A);
```

User Redux File

```
const initState = { username: "", email: "", phone: "" }
export default (state=initState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "LOAD":  
         state.username = action.data.username;
         state.email = action.data.email;
         state.phone = action.data.phone;
         return { ...state }  // error was original here, where I was setting return to state: action.data
      case "ERR":
         return { username: "", email: "", phone: "" }
      default:
         return state;
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably that `user` is simply undefined at first. I'm guessing this is data that is fetched from some kind of asynchronous external dependency (e.g database)?

Comment: Is the initial state of the user an empty object? `{}`

Comment: @Chris that's right, user is fetched from a database. The initial state of user is an object with empty values (e.g., username, email, phone number). Redux devtools shows that the state does update properly with the user data, but crashes when A attempts to pass these fields as props to B.

Comment: Seems unlikely. Have you tried logging `user` in `A`? Your error probably says that it cannot read `username` because `user` is undefined. This isn't a component-sync issue (that doesn't really exist in React), it's most likely that your components are not taking into account that `user` is undefined at first, or, that you have somehow passed/read the wrong variable/property.

Comment: @EmileBergeron the initial state of user is an object with fields but empty values (e.g., user = { username: "", email: "", phone: "" })

Comment: Please include the reducer that updates the user data.

Comment: @Chris When I comment out component B from component A and log the user, it renders twice - once as null, once as undefined. Redux on the other hand does show that the user is loaded and displays the fields correctly. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Ok, so the logging explains why your component crashes. It never gets the expected value. As @EmelieBergeron said, it's probably something in your reducer.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I found the error - in the user reducer, when it receives data, it embedded the data as an object (user: { username: '' ...}  became user: { state: { username: "" , ...} }). Thank you both very much for helping me figure this out!

Comment: Then, you should update your question with the reducer and post an answer with the fixed reducer code and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is user on first render for A is also null/undefined so that's exactly what it passes to B, hence the error.

All you have to do is check if user exists before returning B else return `null`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import B from './B';

const A = ({ user }) => {
   if(!user)
       return null;
   return (
      <B user={user} />
   )
}

A.propTypes = {
   user: PropTypes.object
}
const mapStateToProps = state = ({ user: state.user });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(A);
```

Comment: If the user was not an object, it would fail at `user.username`.

Comment: How is it not an object when you are doing user.username?

Comment: You should not down vote an answer based on a hypothetical scenario

Comment: I possibly misread the comment in OP's question, but it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an if/then statement? Like:

```
import React from 'react';

const B = props => {
  if (props.user && typeof props.user.username !== "undefined"){
    const user = props.user;
    const username = user.username;
    return (
      <div>
        {username}  // throws an error on render, as props.user is undefined
      </div>
    )
  } else{
    'Loading'
  }
}

export default B;
```